# While trying to create a YAML file from a hash, my key ends up with quotations in it

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to take a YAML that looks like this and make a new YAML with the TLD the top-level:

```
---
-
TLD: .abogado
Registry: 
TLD Type: nTLD
-
TLD: .ac
Registry: 
TLD Type: ccTLD
```

I loop through it, taking the TLD as the hash key and the rest as the value for that key.

```
cleaned_chart = {}
rc.each do |item|
  tld_key = item['TLD']
  cleaned_chart[tld_key] = item
end
```

Then I dump the hash to a file:

```
File.open("db/data/open_srs/tld_reference_chart.yml","w") do |file|
  file.write cleaned_chart.to_yaml
end
```

But I'm confused as to why there are quotations around the key now?!

```
".abogado":
  tld: ".abogado"
  tld_type: nTLD
".ac":
  tld: ".ac"
  tld_type: ccTLD
```

I can't seem to remove the quotations! If it's a string, it gets put automatically, same as if I convert to a symbol then I get the : before the key :(

Does anyone know why this is the case? I've googled but can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of YAML serializers err on the side of caution, especially when rendering keys with irregular characters in them. Dot, dash, spaces, these are things that need special handling.

There's nothing wrong with that output, in fact it's probably the best version of that, the most reliably escaped, so that other YAML readers will process it properly.

I'd avoid trying to remove those quotes. If anything, maybe you could switch how your keys are stored to avoid the dot.

Comment: Ahhh, that's really interesting, thank you for the explanation!